# Where can I find Arabic grammar exercises?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, physical-resources, arabic

I'm learning literature Arabic (or what is it called?). I had no trouble finding learning materials, but I want to practice the grammar I have learned.

Where can I find exercises in Arabic grammar with solutions? Doesn't matter if it is in English or in Arabic, or if it's from sites or books.

Answer (score 7):

First, you're referring to Modern Standard Arabic (MSA).
Second, there is this famous [FSI Arabic Course](http://www.fsi-language-courses.net/fsi-written-arabic-course/). It is quite comprehensive over several volumes.

Here are some grammar books with exercises:

- [Easy Arabic Grammar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071462104)
- [Arabic Grammar: A First Workbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521293014)
- [Basic Arabic: A Grammar and Workbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415587735)
- [Arabic Grammar in Context](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415715962)
- [Arabic in 10 Minutes a Day](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1931873321)

Here are some online grammar resources:

- [Arabic Worksheets](https://arabicadventures.com/tag/arabic-worksheet/)
- [All the Arabic you never learned the first time around](http://allthearabicyouneverlearnedthefirsttimearound.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/All-The-Arabic-Searchable-PDF.pdf)
- [Arabic grammar course](http://www.arabic-studio.com/arabic-grammar-course/)